# Error cargando datos con AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql, ajax

Cada vez que le doy al botón para que me cargue el AJAX, me carga la pantalla de inicio con todo (cabecera, menu y footer) aparte de que no me carga los datos de la tabla que pido.
Me sale este error en la consola: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check.
He probado a poner el async: true e también el script al final del documento, pero nada.

Estos son los dos archivos:
Archivo Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sistema de Administración de Envíos - Pedidos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require('components/menu.php');
    ?>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="top-pedidos">
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><button id="buttonFechaPedido" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></div>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputFechaPedido" name="fecha">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button id="buttonNumeroPedido"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumeroPedido" name="npedido" placeholder="Nº pedido">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button id="buttonEstadoPedido"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></button></div>
                    <select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inputEstadoPedido" name="estado">
                        <option value="vacio" selected></option>
                        <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                        <option value="Aceptado">Aceptado</option>
                        <option value="Rechazado">Rechazado</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <a href="nuevo-pedido.php"><button class="newPedido btn btn-primary">Nuevo Pedido</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tables">
            <?php 
            require('sql/sql-pedidos.php');
            ?>
            <div id="tablaPedido">
                <p id="emptyFecha" class="mistake red">Debes poner una fecha</p>
                <p id="errorFecha" class="mistake red">Ha ocurrido un error con la fecha</p>
                <p id="emptyNumero" class="mistake red">Debes poner un número de pedido</p>
                <p id="errorNumero" class="mistake red">Ha ocurrido un error con el número de pedido</p>
                <p id="emptyEstado" class="mistake red">Debes seleccionar un estado</p>
                <p id="errorEstado" class="mistake red">Ha ocurrido un error con el estado</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
        require('components/footer.php');
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Archivo 2

```
<?php
    //Tabla inicial sin parámetros de búsqueda
    require('conexionbd.php');

    $general = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos';
    $result = mysql_query($general) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-pedidos-g'>\n";
    echo "<tr class='superior'>
            <td>Nº pedido</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
        </tr>";

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
?>

<script>
            $('#buttonFechaPedido').click(function() {
            $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
            $('.table-pedidos-n').hide();
            $('.table-pedidos-e').hide();
            var valorFecha = $('#inputFechaPedido').val();
            if (valorFecha.length == 0){
                $('#emptyFecha').removeClass('mistake');
            }
            else{
                $.ajax({
                    data:  valorFecha,
                    url:   'pedidos/pfechas.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                    },
                    error:function (){
                        $('#errorFecha').removeClass('mistake');
                    },
                    success:  function (response) {
                        $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }       
        });
</script>

<script>
    $('#buttonNumeroPedido').click(function() {
        $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-f').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-e').hide();
        var valorNumero =$('#inputNumeroPedido').val();
        if (valorNumero.length == 0){
            $('#emptyNumero').removeClass('mistake');
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                data:  valorNumero,
                url:   'pedidos/pnumero.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                error:function (){
                    $('#errorNumero').removeClass('mistake');
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                }
            });
        }       
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#buttonEstadoPedido').click(function() {
        $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-n').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-f').hide();
        var valorEstado =$('#inputEstadoPedido').val();
        if (valorEstado == 'vacio'){
            $('#emptyEstado').removeClass('mistake');
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                data:  valorEstado,
                url:   'pedidos/pestado.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                error:function (){
                    $('#errorEstado').removeClass('mistake');
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                }
            });
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perdón me da un mensaje de advertencia. Acabo de probar tu respuesta y sigue igual. Gracias de antemano por tu tiempo

Answer (score 2):

1. Primeramente recomendaría revisar tus bibliotecas, y asegurarte que las mismas están **actualizadas**.
2. En segundo lugar, por como llamas a tus métodos que manejan las respuestas Ajax, se nota que tienes código obsoleto. Además, `success` y `error` son obsoletos desde jQuery 3, se recomienda usar `done` y `fail`. Lo mismo ocurre con `document.ready`, que es sustituido por `function`.

Como solución propongo lo siguiente:

1. Encerrar todo el código jQuery dentro de este bloque:

   ```
   $(function() {

   //Aquí tu código jQuery
   //function es la opción recomendada, en lugar de document.ready

   });
   ```
2. Actualizar tus peticiones Ajax:

   - Cambiando `type` por `method`
   - Cambiando `error` por `fail`
   - Cambiando `success` por `done`
   - Quitando cualquier `async` que tengas

   Las peticiones quedarían así:

   ```
            $.ajax({
               data:  valorFecha,
               url:   'pedidos/pfechas.php',
               method:  'post',
               beforeSend: function () {
                   $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
               },
               fail:function (){
                   $('#errorFecha').removeClass('mistake');
               },
               done:  function (response) {
                   $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
               }
           });
   ```

Para más detalles sobre el uso de las peticiones Ajax, puedes consultar la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) actual de jQuery al respecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, las librerías las tengo totalmente actualizadas.
Acabo de probar tu solución y ahora no me da los errores de antes, pero no me carga nada.

Comment: ¿Y la otra parte del código también @auremanci?

Comment: Si, lo he puesto a todo. Había quitado el beforeSend y no hacía nada. Pero al volver a ponerlo se queda en esa función y no hace más nada.